# Converted .py file from Qt5 .ui file via pyuic5 contains a weird import line in the end of the file

Tags: python, qt-designer

I am creating a GUI using Qt Designer (ver. 5.9.7) in macbook (OS Monterey 12.2.1).

When I convert the .ui file into .py file via pyuic5, the output .py file always contains 'import Penta_gif_02.gif' in the very last line, but have no idea where this weird import line came from.

The gif file is my own gif file which has nothing to do with this .ui file (have no idea how this local image ended up in my .ui file!)
Presumably, I wrongly added my local gif file into .ui file at some point but cannot find where I can remove it.

Could anyone help me out please. Thanks.

Here is the summary of my output Qt .py code

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'SView.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #... *snip* ...#
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        #... *snip* ...#
        self.tab_pca.setTabText(self.tab_pca.indexOf(self.tn_graph), _translate("MainWindow", "Graph"))
        self.menuMenu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu"))
        self.actionPreference.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Preference"))
import Penta_gif_02_rc
```

Comment: There's nothing weird about it - it's there because you used a resource file.

Comment: Many thanks ekhumoro and my bad for a nooby question. I found the image from the resource browser and successfully deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem thanks to the ekhumoro's comment!
Here is a solution Just for people who are as noob as I am.

1. Open the .UI file via Qt Designer.
2. From the Resource Browser window, go to 'edit resources'.
3. Select the resource which you want to delete, and then click the 'remove' button.